# ldapjs authentication error

Tags: node.js, authentication, ldap

My company has a ldap server, I try to test the ldap connection using nodejs with ldapjs module, I just want to test the connection at the first place, so no search function is included.

here is the code:

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res){
  var ldap = require('ldapjs');
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'LDAP://192.168.3.220/'
  });

  client.bind(username, password, function (err) {
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }else{
      res.send('login');        
  });
};
```

when I input correct username and password, it sends back "login", which is expected.
when I input correct username but wrong password, it sends back the err object, which is also expected.

here is the problem:
when I input valid username or invalid username (such as "fjdkfjdklsjfsjd") without password, it also sends back "login", which is abnormal.

I am new to ldap and ldapjs, so it might be just a simple mistake but I could not figure it out. Please help....

Answer (score 3):

For binding, you need to pass the dn and the password associated to an entry in the LDAP, not directly the username / password.

So make a basic anonymous search, grab the dn from the result and then try a bind with that dn and the password the user entered.

```
var ldapres = null

var opts = {
  filter: '(username='+ username +')',
  scope: 'sub',
}

client.search('ou=people,dc=company,dc=com', opts, function (err, result) {

  result.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
    ldapres = entry.raw
  })

  result.on('end', function (result) {
    if (!ldapres) { return res.send('Invalid username') }

    client.bind(ldapres.dn, password, function (err) {
      if (err) { return res.send('Wrong password') }
      res.send('You are logged')
    })

  })
})
```

I assume you want to target the attribute username in your LDAP, but you can change it, same as the `ou` and `dc` fields of the search.

Answer (score 0):

It's after a long time But hopefully, this will help someone.

***"here is the problem: when I input valid username or invalid username (such as "fjdkfjdklsjfsjd") without password, it also sends back "login", which is abnormal."***

No, There is something called **"anonymous" bind** in LDAP. Which allows you to bind without a password.
So why?. The reason is to Search in LDAP you need to BIND first, so instead of using a dedicated user for search operations, some prefer the anonymous bind. so for this reason only, the anonymous bind should be used.

**IMPORTANT**

Therefore when you user LDAP you need to handle both empty password and empty DN scenarios from the developer side instead of passing it to the LDAP server

P.S: In some directory services, this could be turned off